# Исключения в конструкторе и утечка памяти на C++

Tags: c++, классы, исключения, конструктор, c++17

Вот допустим у меня есть такой класс:

```
class A {
    std::string str;
    int *ptr;
public:
    A(std::string& str) : str(str), ptr(new int(2)) {
        if (str.size() == 5) {
            throw std::runtime_error("ERROR");
        }
    }
    ~A() {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

Понятно, что из-за вызова исключения в конструкторе должны вызваться деструкторы всех локальных элементов класса. Поскольку локальные элементы находятся в стеке, то для поля `str` деструктор вызовется, но ведь поле `ptr` находится не на стеке, а в heap, откуда элементы нужно удалять вручную. В связи с чем и возник вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что для поля `ptr` деструктор не будет вызван, поскольку это не локальная переменная, которая хранится в стеке, а переменная, хранящаяся в heap, и в итоге на протяжении всей программы у нас мало того, что будет неосвобожденная память на стеке от объекта класса `A`, поскольку деструктор так и не был вызван, так еще и неосвобожденная память в heap от поля `ptr` (утечка памяти в двух местах)?

Comment: Сам `A` не утечет, а вот int - да.

Comment: используйте умные указатели или std::vector и память будет освобождена даже в этом случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> поле ptr находится не на стеке

Член `ptr` находится там, где создается объект `A`, а в стеке это или где еще — вопрос второй. А вот память, на которую он указывает, будет в куче, и действительно не будет освобождена, так как пока конструктор не завершится, объекта нет, и деструктор вызван не будет.

Говорить об "утечке" от локального объекта не приходится, так как по выходе из функции стековая память просто будет "освобождена" (это немного не то освобождение, что при `delete` — она просто будет использована при последующих вызовах. Но вот если создавать объект в куче через `new A` — ситуация усложняется...

Все эти вопросы достаточно тщательно разобраны в книгах Саттера "[Решение сложных задач на С++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0352-1.html)" и "[Новые сложные задачи на С++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0823-X.html)", несмотря на то, что изданы они еще до появления C++11.

Comment: и память самого объекта тоже не будет освобождена, верно?

Comment: Я как раз дописывал об этом, когда вы спросили. Что считать освобождением памяти самого объекта? Например, `void f(){ int i; }` — память `i` освобождена или нет? :)

Comment: Получается, что если у меня этот объект класса находится внутри какой-то функции, то по факту не имеет значения вызывается ли у меня деструктор или нет, так и так по выходе из функции эта память будет освобождена, так?

Comment: если переменная "автоматическая" ("созданная на стеке"), то деструктор для нее будет вызван автоматически и ручками вызывать НЕ НУЖНО. Но я чувствую, что у Вас ещё есть большущее непонимания того, что происходит

Comment: @nameisnoname Деструктор никак не связан с освобождением памяти, которую занимает собственно сам объект.

Comment: @KoVadim Так а можете тогда объяснить, чтобы пришло это понимание?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А в чем тогда суть деструктора? Я думал, что его суть именно в уничтожении объекта.

Comment: В уничтожении объекта, но не выделенной для него памяти.

Comment: @nameisnoname прочитайте базовое, Страуструпа. А потом у Вас будут более прицельные вопросы. А пересказывать пару глав не хочется

Comment: @nameisnoname Ну, вот вы же в своем примере в нем делаете `delete ptr;`. Вот вам и суть деструктора. Кроме этого он автоматически вызывает деструкторы всех полей, если они есть. Но больше ничего не делает.